# Как правильно использовать generics в Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

`Delphi` выдает в этом месте ошибку:

> Operator not applicable to this operand type

```
class function func<t>(value: t);
begin
    value := value mod 2;
end;
```

Это нормальная ситуация, и я просто неправильно использую `generics` или в коде что-то не так написал?

Вкратце о задаче: мне нужно создать одну функцию для работы с разными типами целочисленных переменных, которая будет работать в зависимости от размера конкретной переменной, переданной программистом. Планировалось что-то вроде этого:

```
res := obj.func<integer>(value);
res := obj.func<byte>(value);
...
```

Если это неправильное использование `generics`, буду рад узнать, в чем именно ошибка.

Comment: А как быть компилятору, если t  будет, например, числом с точкой, или строкой, или даже со знаком (отрицательным), а то и рекордом? То есть вам по идее надо както ограничить подмножество разрешенных типов .. Расскажите, какая у вас исходная проблема? (почему, например, не просто функция с параметром типа Cardinal?)

Comment: для вашей задачи, очевидно, `T` должен принимать целочисленный  вид, однако подобных ограничений дженериков в delphi не существует. Самое близкое ограничение здесь - `func<T:record>`, которое ограничивает параметра `T` value-типами. То есть на уровне дженериков не получится ограничить только различные целочисленные параметры

Comment: в целом вы сможете написать эту логику используя знания из `typInfo` и `sizeof(T)`, но приплетание `rtti` для математических операций будет нескольким оверхэдом.

Comment: @Kromster, исходная проблема в том, что необходима функция, которая в зависимости от размера целочисленного значения, переданного в нее, должна выполнять некоторые действия. Если просто передавать `Cardinal`, то размер всегда будет один и тот же.

Comment: @Nup Расписывайте исходную проблему подробнее. Похоже что это проблема X-Y (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/177188)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Это нормальная ситуация, и я просто неправильно использую generics или в коде что-то не так написал?

По определению, оператор `mod` выполняет операцию **целочисленного** деления с возвратом остатка. В качестве операндов для этого оператора допустимо использовать только целые числа (`Byte`, `Word`, `Cardinal`, `Integer`, `Int64`, `UInt64` ...), а все другие типы запрещены, о чём вам и говорит компилятор.

Под капотом, при целочисленном делении используются ассемблерные команды `div` (для беззнаковых типов) и `idiv` (для типов со знаком). И всё отличие деления чисел с разной битностью заключается лишь в том, в какие регистры будут помещены операнды и в каких регистрах будет результат (остаток). Подробнее про регистры можете почитать [тут](http://sadda.ru/pages/assembler-masm32/div/div.htm).

На 32-х битной платформе, для деления 64-битных целых используются встроенные процедуры `__llmod`, `__llumod`, поскольку в этом случае такие числа хранятся сразу в 2-х регистрах и их невозможно элегантно разделить одной командой.

---

> мне нужно создать одну функцию для работы с разными типами целочисленных переменных, которая будет работать в зависимости от размера конкретной переменной

Если вам очень хочется использовать дженерики, то можете воспользоваться вот таким вариантом:

```
class function TMyClass.DoMod<T>(const AValue: T): Integer;
begin
  if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Byte) then begin
    Result := PByte(@AValue)^ mod 5;
  end else if TypeInfo(T) = TypeInfo(Integer) then begin
    Result := PInteger(@AValue)^ mod 5;
  end else begin
    Assert(False, 'Неожиданный тип входной переменной!');
  end;
end;
```

Только не забудьте перечислить все типы, с которыми вы намерены работать.

Comment: спасибо. Вопрос еще и в том, насколько правильно в данной ситуации использовать `generics` и, если это неправильно, как обойтись без их использования.

Comment: @nup вы не описали конкретно, что вы хотите сделать в вашей функции. Возможно множество вариантов реализации, в зависимости от требований к задаче и на что делается упор (быстродействие/читаемость кода/удобство использования). Дженерики это скорее про удобство использования, а если вам надо выжать максимум производительности, несмотря ни на что, то надо писать несколько перегруженных (`overload`) функций для каждого входного типа.

Comment: в функции результат тоже должен был быть `T`, наверное

Comment: А пример без if через case можно?